# React/node build error. Could not find a declaration file for module 'history'. 'node_modules/history/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, history.js

My project is suddenly having a build error. My current repo still has no problem, it only happens when I clone the repo to a new folder and install the package again then do npm run build.
So I am so scared to update the package right now...

I checked the merge history, I don't think any code merge should cause this issue..

Here is the error message I got:

```
$ npm run build

> container-client@2.32.0 build I:\ds\projects\new\container-service\client
> craco build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

I:/ds/projects/new/container-service/client/src/views/add-application/AddApplicationPage.tsx
TypeScript error in I:/ds/projects/new/container-service/client/src/views/add-application/AddApplicationPage.tsx(4,25):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'history'. 'I:/ds/projects/new/container-service/client/node_modules/history/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  If the 'history' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/history`  TS7016

    2 | import './_index.scss';
    3 | import store from '../../store';
  > 4 | import { History } from 'history';
      |                         ^
```

This is the package.json:

```
  {
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "~17.0.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "~2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "~17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "~5.2.0"
  },

Looks like the library "history" is causing the problem.
```

I tried:

1. delete the node_module --> npm install --> npm run build --> same error
2. clone the project again --> npm install --> npm run build --> same error
3. clone the older version of the project --> npm install --> npm run build --> same error

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the new `history` needs a dependency library `@types/history`.  I did a `npm i @types/history@4.7.9` and then did a `npm i` again.  This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

the problem seems to be from the `history` package that you are using

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'history'.

<del>try installing types for the package</del>

<del>npm i @types/history</del>

<del>if that didn't work, then change the import to require</del>

<del>const history = require("history")</del>

### update

the `@types/history` is deprecated and since version 5 of `history`, the type declarations are provided inside the package itself.
updating the package should fix the issue:

```
npm install history@latest
```

Comment: I tried both, the first one. I got the same error. Then I tried to use required instead of import, it is showing another error… history.push() is not defined..  Any more tips please?

Comment: yep. I just visited their [github](https://github.com/remix-run/history) page and it looks like they have added the declaration types inside the package itself. to cut it short, you don't need the  @types/history package. just update history package to its latest version

Comment: Why was my comment deleted? There was a big change from history v4 to history v5, and lots of people are unable to upgrade to v5. So if they've added a declaration file to v5, that won't work for those of us on v4. Upgrading to the latest version won't work for everybody. Do we know if there is a solution for v4 users?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its as common package you would install your package and the type declarations

```
npm install history
npm install --save-dev @types/history
```

and include the types in your project within the tsconfig compilerOptions -

- typeRoots for where the compiler needs to look
- types - the actual library names that can be found in typeRoots

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types"
],
"types": ["history"]
```